# Nuget installs System.Console as dependency for my UWP library

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, nuget

I created a library for UWP apps. project.json is like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections.NonGeneric": "4.0.1-*",
    "System.Collections.Specialized": "4.0.1-*",
    "System.Net.Requests": "4.0.11-*",
    "System.Net.Security": "4.0.0-*",
    "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms": "4.2.0-*",
    "System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs": "4.0.0-*",
    "System.Globalization.Extensions": "4.0.1-*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2-*",
        "System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation": "4.0.0-*"
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0-*",
        "System.Xml.XmlDocument": "4.0.1-*",
        "System.Net.NetworkInformation": "4.1.0-*",
        "System.Net.NameResolution": "4.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.Win32.Registry": "4.0.0-*",
        "System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I created a nuget package, looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>...</id>
    <version>...</version>
    <title>...</title>
    <authors>...</authors>
    <owners>...</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <licenseUrl>...</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>...</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl?...</iconUrl>
    <description>...</description>
    <summary>...</summary>
    <releaseNotes>...</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>...</copyright>
    <tags>...</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.3">
        <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I.e. there is no dependency info for UWP lib yet.

However, when installing this package, nuget prompts me to install System.Console package.

[image]

I'm pretty sure I never access Console in my library, neither Dependency Walker sees any references to it. Why could this happen? Is it possible that some other library from project.json dependencies indirectly depends on it? I wandered though referenced libs' dependencies in Dependency Walker but couldn't find anything on the first level (the dependency tree goes quite deeply to find each and every dependency manually).

How can I identify which reference causes System.Console dependency to appear? And is it OK at all? I was under impression that Console and UWP don't come along well.

Nuget 3.5, Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dependency of NETStandard.Library with version 1.6.0 in your nuget package. Then you can check the dependencies for the NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 in the Package Manager UI or [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/1.6.0), find out the dependency System.Console (>= 4.0.0) is referenced by the NETStandard.Library:

[image]

And it`s OK at all after install the NuGet package UniApp. Below is my project.json file after install that package successfully.

[image]